# Microsoft USD - Closing all active tabs inside USD but keep the session active

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, unified-service-desk

Okay this might be a simple task but sorry for asking as i am quite new to USD.

What i want is to close all the active tabs inside USD but I do not want to close the current active session.

I am using CloseSession action to perform this on SessionTabs but it closes my active session as well i just want to close the active tabs without closing the active session.

Comment: Could you please explain your requirement? You mentioned what you want to do is to close all the active tabs inside USD but keep your current session open. But at what point this logic should work, from the solution you mentioned I assume that the same is done on Closing of a session. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Your active tabs all have a Close action of their very own. If a tab could be active, just call its Close action and your session will remain. You'll need one Action Call for each tab that you want to close.